# Better way to read XML in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a page which will receive xml data as post request, and according to the data provided i have to do some function.
But here the problem is the xml data that i am getting is some what identical. Please find a good way to identify the format.
this is the first XML

```
<GLOBAL>
 <DATA>
  <NAME>asdasd</NAME>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <PARENT>Mother</PARENT>
  </DATA>
 <DATA>
  <NAME>asdasd</NAME>
    <ID>2</ID>
  <PARENT>Father</PARENT>
</DATA>
 </GLOBAL>
```

and the second xml is

```
    <GLOBAL>
 <DATA>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <NAME>asdasd</NAME>
  <BILL>
      <AMT>3500.00</AMT>
  </BILL>
  <BILL>
      <AMT>1200.00</AMT>
  </BILL>
</DATA>
 <DATA>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <NAME>abcdefg<NAME>
  <BILL>
   <AMT>3100.00</AMT>
  </BILL>
</DATA>  
 <GLOBAL>
```

Please help me to get a better solution

Comment: *"Please help me to get a better solution"* - Helping you to get a better solution would require a solution to be there in the first place. Otherwise there is nothing we can improve on. You didn't show what you have so far. Or even what your problem is.

Comment: Sorry for that, Here the first xml is for person details and the second one is for person bill details and according to which xml request that i am getting, the details should insert to the table. then how to identify  the xml format dynamicaly, please give some sample code

Comment: Specify how you are reading the xml.Which control you are using to display/manipulate the data. Ex: Displaying using Gridview/List View controls.....
Provide the code you use for enhancement/modification

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse your XML documents, you can use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class.
With this class you can write LINQ command to fetch your data from XML documents.

Answer (score 1):

Create a DTD for both the formats and match against it.

Hope it helps.

Check this link [How To Validate an XML Document by Using DTD, XDR, or XSD in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307379)